# VSCode Terminal "The connection to the terminal's pty host process is unresponsive, the terminals may stop working."

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Whenever trying to run my code or do anything via powershell/cmd/gitbash, entering text often takes more than a few seconds to show if even at all, doesn't let my program run, and proceeds to show the dialog `The connection to the terminal's pty host process is unresponsive, the terminals may stop working.` Any fix? This happens on any language I try (Go, PY)

Comment: Same problem here, I don't find solution

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. I'm using zsh on MacOs.
The problem was that I think I corrupted the .zprofile file in Users/{userName} directory.
In my case there was one line causing the problem:

```
export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libbdplus/0.2.0/lib"
```

After removing the line and restarting the whole VS code it's working.